# Not able to publish to SNS topic from an ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-sns

I have an docker image with an API that publishes provided request body to a SNS topic. Now I am able to perform this operation locally, but when I deploy this image to ECS through ECR, I get following error form AWS Go SDK(v2) after ~1 min of request initiation.

```
https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , canceled, context canceled
```

I have verified following things:

1. ECS service (as well as EC2 as I am using EC2 launch type) has a role that grants full access to SNS
2. SNS access policy allows all requests from current AWS account.
3. I am able to publish to same topic after logging into EC2 instance.
4. API request has 5 min timeout.
5. I am using default VPC.

For the sake of experiment, I am not using HTTPS and attached security group allows all traffic on port 80. I tried everything but didn't find what's wrong. I would appreciate your great help, thanks.

Comment: "when I deploy this image to ECS through EKS" does not make sense. Are you deploying to ECS or EKS?

Comment: I updated the post, I meant through ECR. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "For the sake of experiment, I am not using HTTPS and attached security group allows all traffic on port 80." SNS will want you to connect to it over SSL, on port 443. Although this sounds like you may be talking about inbound traffic, which is irrelevant to the error you are encountering.

Comment: Does your ECS Task role (not the service role) have access to SNS?

Comment: @MarkB, Yes. ECS Task role has full access to SNS.